# Show table on tableau loaded from Teradata

Tags: teradata, tableau-api

Purpose- I have connected tableau desktop and Teradata to load a table with 7 columns (2 of them dates) and 500 rows (It keeps adding rows along daily). I want to create a dashboard or workbook with the same table (7x500) with a data range, so my stakeholder can update dates and export the table.

I have done:
Once is load in "Data source", I have gone to "Sheet 1" and add "Dimensions" to "row", and one of the dates to "Filters"...
I see that there is a column with values "abc" that stays there with no value. When I add more than 6 "Dimensions" to "row", it merges 2 columns (See screenshot)

Is this possible to do?
Any thoughts how?

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEZPI.png)

Answer (score 2):

Go to Analysis > Table Layout > Advanced and change the Columns setting to a larger number (but you can only go to 16 max)

The 'abc' and a few other things that you're doing are showing that you're not using Tableau the right way.  It's a visualisation tool, not a spreadsheet/export tool.  It MIGHT work for you, but building text tables like this is really hard & slow for Tableau.

The 'abc' is because you don't have anything on Columns and not showing anything continuous.

Also, your stakeholder won't be able to change the dates in Tableau - it doesn't support data entry at all (natively), you can use an extension in the recent versions but it's still not as simple as "click the cell, enter the new value"

Comment: Helpful! Thanks @cmcau